# react-native iOS 16 Xcode 14 This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After updating to Xcode 14 and iOS 16 I Got  this purple warning on build time and its about 30 to 40 warnings. is there any solutions for this.

```
/Users/apple/repos/ssd/iOS/xxxxxxx/main.m:8 This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
```